# how to give scroll view and swipe for total activity view

Tags: android

In my activity i am having listview and and 3 buttons and sliding menu also. if swipe that menu listview is scrolling. how to disable dispatch events for buttons and listview. how i can get which view clicked in dispatchtouchevent.

Answer (score 0):

to disable touch for behind view(your sliding menu or ...) use this

`// Disallow Drawer to intercept touch events.
v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`